# UndefinedTable: relation does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm running with the `python 3.5.2` and trying to run basic commands with `postgres`.

I'm connecting to the postgres docker server:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='docker', host='127.0.0.1', port='5432') 
cursor = self.conn.cursor()
```

For the **first** **time** I'm creating a new table:

```
sql = '''CREATE TABLE ''' + self.table_name + '''(
         FIRST_NAME CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
         LAST_NAME CHAR(20),
         AGE INT,
         SEX CHAR(6),
         INCOME FLOAT
      )'''
cursor.execute(sql)
```

And inserting rows with:

```
def add_emloyee(name, last, age, sex, income):
    sql = '''INSERT INTO ''' + self.table_name + '''(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME, AGE,SEX,INCOME)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
    cursor.execute(sql, (name, last, age, sex, income))
```

Everything works good.
But when I'm running the application again (after I closed it and run again) and comment the create table commands (because I created it in previous run), and trying to insert new data into the table, I'm getting error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "employee" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME, AGE,SEX,INCOME)
```

Why is this happen ?

Comment: Did you remember to commit the changes to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the `commit` command after create table (or add new row)

```
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `flask_sqlalchemy` with `postgres`.

I forgot to give `create_all` in the flask shell which gave me the same error.

```
db.create_all()
```

Hope this helps someone.